# How can I access this.props in componentDidMount. It always return underfined value

Tags: reactjs

I want to access some data of props in `componentDidMount` like below (`this.props.comic.id`) in order to fetch API from server.

But `this.props.comic.id` always returns an `undefined` value for me. I try to check `console.log` it another like `componentDidUpdate`, it returns the correct value.

I can't do fetch in `componentDidUpdate` because I must `setState` and if it does that, an infinite loop will occur.

How can I access it like below?

```
async componentDidMount() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
            const response = await fetch(`${origin_url_be}/api/user/comic/check?id_comic=${this.props.comic.id}`, {
                method: 'get',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }).then((response) => response.json());
    
            // this.setState({
            //     isLike: response.result.isLike,
            //     isFollow: response.result.isFollow,
            // })
    
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's not present yet, it depends on the parent component

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox on this? It will be easier to debug